# mdframed font option is not working

Tags: fonts, mdframed

Although the [`mdframed` manual (v1.3a)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) mentions the general option `font`, it is not being obeyed, as can be verified with the test document below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[font=\sffamily\slshape]
  \lipsum[88]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

The typeset document looks like the following:

[image: test document]

Notice how the body of the `mdframed` environment is not typeset in a sans serif slanted font, as requested in the source document.

Is this a bug with `mdframed`?

Comment: Are you sure you have v1.3a? Add a `\listfiles` to your preamble and check the `.log` file to check.

Comment: 1.3a is only about 10 days old, and I don't think that option is in 1.2

Comment: @Seamus, with `\listfiles` in the preamble I confirm the version: `mdframed.sty    2012/02/04 v1.3a: mdframed`

Comment: Searching the manual I can find a definition for the `font` key (at line 176), but I do not see it used anywhere in the implementation.

Comment: I guess your best bet is to wait and see if @Marco Daniel (the author of `mdframed`) shows up to answer your question.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Write the author.

Comment: Until this super-bug is fixed, just write `\begin{mdframed}\sffamily\slshape` and save a few keystrokes in the process.

Comment: I forgot this definition. I will fix this.

Comment: As a bug report, this is 'too localized' as a Q&A question.